# iAd Causing constraint conflictions

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, iad

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my constraints... `Storyboard` thinks there are some conflicting `constraints` but not that I can see from what I've set manually.

Apparently these are the conflicting constraints:

```
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc9a0431200 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc9a0587fc0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc9a040e210 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc9a0587fc0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fc9a0584b10 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc9a0404300 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc9a0588ad0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc9a0400e00 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc9a0588ad0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc9a0584b10.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9a0584860 V:[UIImageView:0x7fc9a0584f90(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9a058afb0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc9a0587fc0]-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fc9a0584f90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9a058b280 V:[UIImageView:0x7fc9a0584f90]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc9a0588ad0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9a0775890 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fc9a0584b10(320)]>"
)
```

Can anyone help me figure out what it thinks is going on? I am using size classes but from what I can see all the correct constraints are installed/uninstalled..

Ok it seems that `iAd` is causing my `constraints` to mess up in landscape... hopefully disabling banner ads in landscape will solve this..

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your `iAd banner` in code I always prefer it this way.

Here is some working code for you that just worked for me. The ad automatically changes the size according to the screen size and is located at the bottom of the screen.

```
import iAd

class viewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var AdBanner = ADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Ad Banner Settings */

        AdBanner = ADBannerView()
        AdBanner.frame = CGRectZero
        AdBanner.delegate = self
        self.AdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.AdBanner.frame.size.height, self.AdBanner.frame.size.width, self.AdBanner.frame.size.height)
        AdBanner.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view .addSubview(AdBanner)

}

/* All iAd Functions */

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
/* whatever you need */
    return true
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    AdBanner.hidden = false
}


func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error Loading Ad")
/* whatever you need */
    AdBanner.hidden = true
}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}
```